# Dark Theme in android 9.0 changes my app layouts ugly

Tags: android, android-theme, android-dark-theme

I am just designing my layout without expecting any of the problems, but one-day android 9.0 launched and I brought the phone and installed my app in it and tried my app opening it with night mode ON and I started to see white color layout changes in dark and my minds goes block. I want to know how to disable the theme.

```
I tried changing themes, changing the background colors none of those works

<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-15dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tableTxt"
        android:background="@drawable/table_no_orders_border"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cv_one_login"
            android:layout_width="189dp"
            android:layout_height="199dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="1dp"
            app:cardElevation="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0.1dp">

            <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/sv1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="147dp"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"
                    android:scrollbarSize="10dp"
                    android:isScrollContainer="true">
                <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tableItems"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:text="@string/table"
                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/TextcolorforBlack"/>
            </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/totalTableBill"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="@string/total_bill"
                    android:textColor="@color/SettingsColor"
                    android:layout_below="@id/sv1"
                    android:textAlignment="gravity"
                    android:gravity="bottom"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I need my layout as it is designed. even if the theme got applied also it should be the same.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change App theme to any theme in the App Manifest file like,

```
<application 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"/>

<application 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"/>

<application 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black"/>

<application 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault"/>
```

Or you can customize theme in the styles.xml file and then Apply in Manifest

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light"/>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme"/>
```

Now in Manifest file

```
<application 
    android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme"/>
```

You can also preview themes in the preview window in Android Studio.

[image]