# Android Material3 toggle dark mode on click

Tags: android, kotlin, darkmode, material3, lightmode

I want to implement a switch for toggling dark mode in my application. After investigating multiple sources on how to do this correctly, I came across this one-line solution:

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
```

Unfortunately, in my case this only changes the configuration to light mode and doesn't update UI colors. Here's my code:

```
binding.toggleDarkMode.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
   if (isChecked) {
      AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
      activity?.recreate()
   }
}
```

I'd also like to mention that I have separate theme files for light and dark mode. Light theme extends `Theme.Material3.Light.NoActionBar` and dark theme extends `Theme.Material3.Dark.NoActionBar`. Could anyone tell me what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically my phone's OS was overriding my app's styles on a MUI device. Here's the complete answer:
[Can't disable Night Mode in my application even with values-night](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63781371/cant-disable-night-mode-in-my-application-even-with-values-night)

Comment: Oh that sucks. I know MIUI can use force-dark but I've never seen an issue with stuff that actually uses dark themes, maybe that disabled `forceDarkAllowed` attribute is a good one to add in general. Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 1):

That line you posted explicitly sets the theme to light mode

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
```

or to put it another way, "not night mode".

If you want it to toggle, you need to get the current mode (light or dark) and set it to the other one:

```
// check the mode
val isDarkMode = AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode() == NIGHT_MODE_YES
// set the other
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(if (isDarkMode) NIGHT_MODE_NO else NIGHT_MODE_YES)
```

or if you're relying on the switch state, just do `if (isChecked)` instead, no need to `get` the current mode.

---

There are more than two modes btw, it's recommended that you handle the "follow the system" one too but that's up to you - more info about the whole thing [here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/appcompat-v23-2-daynight-d10f90c83e94) from one of the developers.

It also gets into the fact you need to call `setDefaultNightMode` whenever your app starts, as early as possible, so it can be themed correctly - e.g. in a custom `Application` class, although if you're doing a single-activity app you could stick it in `onCreate` there too. Otherwise it would need to go in every `Activity`, just in case that's the one that's created first when the app is opened/restored.

But what this means is **you have to store the light/dark setting** so it can be read when the app starts - it doesn't "stick" to the last thing you set it to. You could use `SharedPreferences` for this, and if your switch is an actual `Preference` that's all handled automatically! But if it's like a toggle on a normal app screen, you'll have to store it yourself

*edit* I knew there was something I wanted to mention - you don't need to do `activity?.recreate()`, `setDefaultNightMode` will handle that for you if it's required (i.e. if there's been a change)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the problem is that after calling MODE_NIGHT_NO I see that the uiMode of my config successfully changes to UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO, but components colors do not switch to light theme, so basically nothing visible happens on the UI

Comment: @Bravo if you're not seeing any change at all anywhere, that sounds like an issue with your themes. Your themes usually have to inherit from `Theme.AppCompat.DayNight` or `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight` rather than a light or dark theme specifically (https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/theming/darktheme#support-dark-theme) so see if Material 3 has a `DayNight` one

Comment: I've changed to Theme.Material3.DayNight, but unfortunately it still doesn't work for me. Although, I should mention that the text color indeed changes to light mode, but buttons, background, etc stays DARK mode

Comment: @Bravo that sounds like parts of your UI are overriding the defaults in the theme, like styling is being applied on another level - out of the box the `MaterialComponents.DayNight` theme has the standard light theme as well as a standard dark variant, so if you're not even getting the normal light theme then check your basic attrs like ``colorPrimary`` and `colorBackground` aren't being overridden with the wrong colours in the light variant

Comment: I know you're using Material 3, but here's the current way to do things, so maybe start here https://material.io/blog/android-dark-theme-tutorial and make sure you've got the basics down, night-qualified resources in the right place, etc. Maybe start with the original theme and start adding your customisation in bit by bit. I haven't used Material 3, but maybe this helps too: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Color.md#using-dynamic-colors (that and the *Custom colors* section below it). That's all I can advise really

Comment: I've just double-checked all my styling files - everything is correct. For testing purposes I removed all the theme overriden values and used plain Theme.Material3.DayNight but the same result is produced. One more important thing to mention - when I toggle dark mode on system level (in settings), then everything works as expected, so this means that my files are in the right place with correct values

Comment: @Bravo are you using an `AppCompatActivity`?

Comment: Yes, I'm using AppCompatActivity and my navigation is fragment-based (just one Activity class)

Comment: @Bravo I'm not sure then, sorry - I'm guessing you're using the AndroidX support `Fragment` class too (I'm not sure if it matters). Also since this behaviour is being triggered by a `CheckedChangedListener`, and those fire when the checked state is *set*, make sure the Activity recreation isn't resetting that switch to off and causing it to default to dark mode or anything. (Personally I tend to prefer click listeners instead, because those only respond to user interactions). I don't know what else to suggest really - see if a simple button setting a specific mode works and go from there?

Comment: Thank you for your help and instructions @cactustictacs. I'll investigate further and let you know if I'll be able to fix this issue

Comment: Found the problem... please have a look at the answer I posted